# How to make a heatmap in python with aggregated/summarized data?

Tags: python, aggregate, coordinates, heatmap

I'm trying to plot some X and Z coordinates on an image to show which parts of the image have higher counts. Y values are height in this case so I am excluding since I want 2D. Since I have many millions of data points, I have grouped by the combinations of X and Z coordinates and counted how many times that value occurred. The data should contain almost all conbinations of X and Z coordinates.  It looks something like this (fake data):

[image]

I have experimented with matplotlib.pyplot by using the plt.hist2d(x,y) function but it seems like this takes raw data and not already-summarized data like I've got.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Note: I can figure out the plotting on an image part later, first I'm trying to get the scatter-plot/heatmap to show aggregated data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure this out. After loading in the data in the format of the original post, step one is pivoting the data so you have x values as columns and z values as rows. Then you plot it using seaborn heatmap. See below:

```
#pivot columns
values = pd.pivot_table(raw, values='COUNT_TICKS', index=['Z_LOC'], columns = ['X_LOC'], aggfunc=np.sum)

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
sns.set(rc={'axes.facecolor':'cornflowerblue', 'figure.facecolor':'cornflowerblue'})
#ax = sns.heatmap(values, vmin=100, vmax=5000, cmap="Oranges", robust = True, xticklabels = x_labels, yticklabels = y_labels, alpha = 1)
ax = sns.heatmap(values, 
                 #vmin=1, 
                 vmax=1000, 
                 cmap="Greens",  #BrBG is also good
                 robust = True, 
                 alpha = 1)
plt.show()
```